# IntelliJ IDEA Quick Fix Customization

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ is picking up a particular error, but I find the quick fix to be unsuitable.  My current situation is that I have a bean unsafely getting a date:

```
public Date getSomeDate() {
   return someDate;
}
```

IntelliJ rightly flags this as a problem under the "*Return of Date or Calendar field*" rule, but offers the following quick fix:

```
public Date getSomeDate() {
   return (Date) someDate.clone();
}
```

When instead, I want:

```
public Date getSomeDate() {
   return new Date(someDate.getTime());
}
```

Can I change the quick fix options to fix this the way I want to?

Comment: Yes, your fix is fine.

Comment: The questions wasn't so much as to whether or not my fix is fine, but rather can I customize IntelliJ's quick fix options to do it like the second example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write your own plugin for IntelliJ IDEA, which implements your quick fix variant. Default quick-fixes are not modifiable.

Comment: I was hoping that wouldn't be the case... so I'm left with IJ's quick fixes and that's it eh?